# longtabu and scrpage2: line breaks in page header cause compilation errors

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, koma-script, tabu, scrpage2

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead[Headline 1\\ Headline 2]{Headline 1\\ Headline 2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{longtabu}{XXX}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that the compilation of this MWE causes the following error:

```
! Misplaced \cr.
\reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr 

l.17 \end{longtabu}

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
or \cr or \span just now. If something like a right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

For one document, I needed a two-line page header and got this error, which — I guess — belongs to the `tabu` package. I can't find any error in it and would be delighted about help how I can get a line break in the page header without this error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the page head is catching longtables version of `\\` easiest is just to avoid the problem by using the alternative form

```
\chead[Headline 1\linebreak Headline 2]{Headline 1\linebreak Headline 2}
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your fast answer, which solved the issue for me.

Comment: arguably it is a bug in the class as if it redefines the headline so multiple lines work, it should locally run LaTeX's `\@parboxrestore` command to ensure that it has the correct definition of `\\ `

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution worked fine, but shouldn’t this be fixed in `longtable` or `scrpage2`? I didn’t understand which package has the bug, but the redefinition that `longtable` does should be local in `{longtable}`, isn’t it?

Comment: The definition of `\\ ` is local to longtable but the page breaker works asynchonously and fires while longtable is active the header code if it is setting up multiline headers should execute `\@parboxrestore` to locally reset the environment including the definition of `\\ ` I suppose LT could do this in its output routine wrapper but the proper place really is in the header code, the standard LaTeX headers are in a one line hbox so it is not an issue there.

Comment: LaTeX's `\@outputpage` does initially call `\@parboxrestore`. So LaTeX's output routine already restores `\\ ` before `\@thehead`. `\chead` uses `\centering` to center the element. This also redefines `\\ ` again. The problem is, that `tabu` redefines `\centering` (and several other usual macros). And this definition is still valid while building the head or foot. So the `\centering` of `\chead` isn't LaTeX's `\centering` while the `longtabu` is active. So the problem is, that `tabu` does not restore the original definitions while the output is active. BTW: It's independent of the class.

Comment: @Schweinebacke oh of course that thanks. Yes that's a well known mis-feature of tabu. I probably didn't really know of tabu in 2012:-)

Answer (score 5):

longtabu redefines (like every tabular) `\\` and in the header this definition is still active and leads to chaos. Use another command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\let\ORInewline\\
\chead[Headline 1\ORInewline Headline 2]{Headline 1\ORInewline Headline 2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{longtabu}{XXX}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Despite your solution solves the issue for me, I think the solution of David Carlisle is the more "clean" one, since I don't need to introduce a new command. Nevertheless, thank you really much for your efforts.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't checked if there already exists a suitable alias. But I will let the answer stay as it can be used as a template in case other commands in the header conflict with longtabu.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by a mis-feature of `tabu`. In `\tabu@init` the package redefines several usual LaTeX commands, like `\centering`, `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` (but also `\fbox`, `\color` etc.). For some of the commands this results in problems, if these are used in the page head or page footer while a `longtabu` is processed. Here is a MWE for this problem without using any page style package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\markright{\protect\parbox{2em}{\protect\centering One\\ Two}}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{longtabu}{lr}
  first & row \\
  second & row \\
  third & row \\
  fourth & row \\
  fifth & row \\
  sixth & row \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

This also gives the error message from the question:

> ```
> ./test-longtabu.tex:15: Misplaced \cr.
> \reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr 
>
> l.15 \end{longtabu}
> ```

A real correction of the problem can only be done by the `tabu` maintainer. `tabu` should either not redefine all those macros or should restore correctly.

However, the easiest workaround for the problem is, not to use `\\` but `\par`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead[Headline 1\par Headline 2]{Headline 1\par Headline 2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{longtabu}{XXX}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

But you should also switch over from deprecated `scrpage2` to `scrlayer-scrpage`. Unfortunately, the current release of `scrlayer-scrpage` does not allow `\par` inside the argument of `\chead` (I've reported this already). This should be fixed in the next release of `scrlayer-scrpage`. Moreover `scrlayer-scrpage` v3.27 will provide a workaround for the `tabu` misfeature. So, with the current version from the subversion repository of KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead*{Headline 1\\ Headline 2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{longtabu}{XXX}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

does already work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and the way to solve it is the replace all the `\\` in the headers/footers definitions with `\newline`.

Also note that the same problem will happen with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: actually `\newline` doesn't trigger the lines to be centered in the same way, you need `\linebreak` to get the same effect as you'd get with `\\ ` without the table.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I used `\newline` in my case and it solved my problem but I wasn't using the centered header or footer but only the left and right ones, and it didn't appear to be a problem in these cases.