# Vertical/Horizontal alignment for multi-line header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, vertical-alignment, scrpage2

I have the following code to create my header

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.6cm,rmargin=2.6cm,headheight=1.3cm,headsep=1cm}
\pagestyle{headings}

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

%%% OPTIONS
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\tabulinesep=^1.5mm_1.5mm    

% Here the relevant code
\usepackage{scrpage2} \pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\small }
\clearscrheadfoot
\rohead{Line1 \\[2pt] Line2 \\[8pt] \normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize{Line3}\\[-37pt]}
\lohead{\rule{2cm}{2cm}\vspace{0.05cm}}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
 Some text just to make a page
\end{document}
```

But at compile time I was having a conflict. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49622/longtabu-and-scrpage2-line-breaks-in-page-header-cause-compilation-errors) I found out that I need to substitute `\\` with `\linebreak` because I am using `longtabu`

Now my question: with the old code `Line3` was below the line created with `\setheadsepline`, now it is above. Is there a way of restoring its position while retaining the `\linebreak` fix?

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments I have tried

```
\makeatletter
%%% HEADERS
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\small }
\clearscrheadfoot
\rohead{Line 1 \@normalcr[2pt] Line 3 \@normalcr[8pt] \normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize{Line 3}\@normalcr[-37pt]}
\lohead{\includegraphics[scale=0.4, trim= -0.0cm 0.05cm 0cm 0cm]{logo.pdf}\vspace{0.05cm}}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\makeatother
```

but the text is aligned in the middle of the page, not on the right side. How can I fix the horizontal alignment?

Note1: I already tested inserting `\hfill` on each line, but it has effect only on the first line, the second and the third are still in the center of the page.

Note2: Tested `\raggedleft`, same result as `\hfill`

**Edit2:** SOLVED

I have no idea if this is the cleanest solution, but it does what I was looking for

```
\makeatletter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\small }
\clearscrheadfoot
\lohead{\includegraphics[scale=0.4, trim= -0.0cm 0.05cm 0cm 0cm]{logo.pdf}\vspace{0.05cm}}
\rohead{Line1 \linebreak \@normalcr[-9pt] Line2 \linebreak\@normalcr[-2pt] \normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize{Line3 \linebreak\@normalcr[-49pt]}}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\linebreak` doesn't really work like `\\ ` you probably want `\newline` or if you need the optional argument `\@normalcr[-37pt` in which case you want `\makeatletter` or put teh code in a local package/class file.

Comment: I have tried `\newline` but instead of obtaining lines right-justified the lines were centered (and it was still in the `\rohead` argument). Any idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Hi @PeterJansson, thank you for the welcome. I am not new to StackExchange, so I thought I knew how to ask a question; is there something not proper in my post?

Comment: Hi, no problem at all. All first posts are subject to a review and we always leave a "Welcome" to "new" (in the sense of a first post) users.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my apologies, I included the full list of packages that I have to use. The logo is 2cm by 2cm.

Comment: @Federico I edited the example so it runs, it isn't clear what you want to change: If you change `\\[-37pt` to `\\[-55pt]` then `line3` comes below the line....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what have you used? `\linebreak` or `\newline`?
I will try to make that change as soon as possible, thanks.
Also, `\\ ` **must** be removed: it conflicts with `longtabu` (not included in the snippet because not relevant now)

Comment: I just used your example as posted, using `\\ ` As I said in the initial comment you can use `\@normalcr` if you need to access the original definition of `\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, I did not understood what you meant there, this aspect of LaTeX is quite new to me. I will try with that command.

Comment: surround your definition with `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` if you use `@`  see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the output is not what I was expecting, have I done something wrong?