# What is causing (and how can I fix) "Misplaced \cr" and "Misplaced alignment tab" errors in an array environment when trying to compile my .dtx?

Tags: errors, arrays, package-writing

I created a small package to help me typeset various tidbits in papers for a specific domain of theoretical computer science that I sometimes work in.  So far, it has been working well, but I decided that I wanted to introduce auto-growing brackets since I can sometimes end up with a whole bunch of nested brackets being displayed.  To do this, I introduced use of the '[perfectcut](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/perfectcut)' package.  Or tried to.

For full reference, you can find the pre-perfectcut implementation [here](https://github.com/jcoo092/LaTeX-cP-systems/blob/master/cpsystems.dtx), and the attempt at a new implementation [here](https://github.com/jcoo092/LaTeX-cP-systems/blob/autogrow_brackets/cpsystems.dtx).  The only substantive difference between the two is changing the definitions of `cpfunc`, `cpsend` and `cprecv`, and introducing the new `cpsystems@functorparens` and `cpsystems@msgbraces` commands to back said new definitions.

The problem is, with just these changes (and, best as I can tell, the modification to `cpfunc` was the only one that actually caused these problems), is that now when I try to re-compile my .dtx file (using the command `pdflatex cpsystems.dtx`), I get a whole bunch of "Misplaced \cr" and "Misplaced alignment tab &" errors.  E.g., the very first ones look like:

```
! Misplaced \cr.
\reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr 
                                  
l.310 ...func{p}{h(R) \cpfunc{p}{h(F)p(P)}}}~c(W)}
                                                  
? 
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<recently read> &
                 
l.310 ...func{p}{h(R) \cpfunc{p}{h(F)p(P)}}}~c(W)}
```

In the full-blown file, these such errors start at [line 310](https://github.com/jcoo092/LaTeX-cP-systems/blob/autogrow_brackets/cpsystems.dtx#L310), with more being reported at lines 315, 370 and 375 (though the latter two are actually a repeat of the earlier two, for documentation reasons).  Going by discussions of these errors that I could turn up, such as [this TeXOverflow question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91559/what-does-misplaced-cr-in-latex-error-mean), or this [Overleaf help page](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Extra%20alignment%20tab%20has%20been%20changed%20to%20%5Ccr), I surmise that the errors are probably not occurring there, but likely on the line above.  Either way, though, I can't work out what the issue really is.

The lines in question are using a package command, which in turn uses an array environment, to present something.  On the previous line, I have included a line break.  I have checked, and am fairly certain I have specified the correct number of & characters on those lines to get everything to fit together, and I didn't see any errors previously.

I have done my best to create an example that reproduces the errors, which is below, though it is still awfully long (I wasn't sure what else I could remove without mucking something up):

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program  = pdfLaTeX
%
% \fi
% \iffalse
%<*readme>
%%cpsystems LaTeX package
%</readme>
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{cpsystems.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{cpsystems}
%<*package>
[2020/07/16 v0.14 Package to aid in typesetting cP systems 
    rulesets, following Nicolescu's standard style]
%</package>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{cpsystems}[2020/07/16 v0.14]
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
%\OnlyDescription %Leave this commented out unless you have read the Doc documentation and know what you're doing
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{cpsystems-autogrow-bracks-mwe.dtx}
  \PrintIndex
  \PrintChanges
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%   \begin{cpruleset}
%       \cprule{s_1}{\cpfunc{v}{v(R)Y}}{1}{s_2}{\cpfunc{s}{r(R)~u(Y)~
%       \cpfunc{p}{h(R)p()}}~c(\lambda)}
%       
%       \cprule{s_2}{\cpfunc{s}{r(R)~u() \\ & \cpfunc{p}{h(F)p(P)} \\ & c(C)}}
%       {+}{s_3}{\cpfunc{z}{\cpfunc{p}{h(R) \cpfunc{p}{h(F)p(P)}}}~c(W)}
%       
%       \cprule{s_2}{}{+}{s_2}{\cpfunc{s}{r(R)~u(Z) \\
%       & & & & \cpfunc{p}{h(T) \cpfunc{p}{h(F) p(P)}}
%       \\ & & & & c(CW)}}
%       
%       \cprule{s_2}{s(\_)}{+}{s_2}{}
%       
%       \cprule{s_3}{}{1}{s_4}{p'(P) \quad c'(1D)}
%   \end{cpruleset}
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%
% \fi
% 
% \subsection{Preamble}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%

\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{framed}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{trimspaces}
\RequirePackage{newfloat}
\RequirePackage{perfectcut}

\newcounter{cpsystems@RuleNum}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newenvironment{cpruleset}
    {\begin{framed}\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.0em}{-1.0em}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}\[\begin{array}{lllllr}}
    {\end{array}\]\end{adjustwidth}\end{framed}}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% % \begin{macro}{\cprule}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\cprule}[5]{
    \refstepcounter{cpsystems@RuleNum}
    \cpsystems@basecprule{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{(\arabic{cpsystems@RuleNum})}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{\cpfunc}
% Command for declaring a cP~systems functor.
% The first argument is the symbol for the functor itself, and the second argument is the objects contained inside the functor.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\cpfunc}[2]{
    \trim@spaces@noexp{#1\cpsystems@functorparens{#2}}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% 
% \begin{macro}{\cpsystems@basecprule}
% For writing out rules inside a |cpruleset| environment.
% Required arguments are, in order, beginning state name; LHS of rule; the label to be applied to the arrow; the ending state name; the RHS of the rule.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\cpsystems@basecprule}[6]{
    \trim@spaces@noexp{#1 & #2 & \rightarrow_{#3} & #4 & #5 & #6\\}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{\cpsystems@functorparens}
% To ensure that brackets resize themselves automatically in functors.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\cpsystems@functorparens}[1]{
    \perfectunary{IncreaseHeight}(){#1}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
%
% \Finale
%
```

In case versions matter, I am using MikTex to run this, and it seems to be reporting its version as 20.6.29.  AmsMath is version 2.17e.  The 'tools' package doesn't have a listed version in the MikTex console but is dated with 'Tue Feb 4 10:11:41 2020'.

Can you see what the problem is?  I imagine it is probably some trivial issue of a misplaced character or something, but I have been unable to figure this out.  (I'm also open to suggestions on other aspects of the package if someone is keen enough :) )

EDIT:  I began to wonder if the perfectcut package actually had anything to do with this problem, and I'm not sure that it does in actuality.  To test this, I removed the `\RequirePackage{perfectcut}` line and modified the definition of `cpsystems@cpfunctorparens` to simply `(#1)`.  I still get the exact same error.  Leaving perfectcut in, but changing the `cpruleset` block to just:

```
\begin{cpruleset}
    \cpfunc{a}{\cpfunc{b}{\cpfunc{c}{d}}}
\end{cpruleset}
```

gives me exactly the expected behaviour.  That said, I did also try to exclude the requirepackage line for perfectcut, but continue using `perfectunary` to define `cpfunc`, and didn't seem to experience any errors with it, so I'm not 100% sure I was doing everything correctly.  Does anybody have any suggestions on what I should do to test this further to determine the problem precisely?

Answer (score 1):

I came back to this today, and I *seem* to have found the problem.  It was, in fact, two-fold.  Firstly, I wasn't using the `perfectunary` environment correctly.  For some daft reason, I wasn't using including all necessary curly braces.  I.e. the definition was

```
\newcommand{\cpsystems@functorparens}[1]{
    \perfectunary{IncreaseHeight}(){#1}
}
```

but should have been

```
\newcommand{\cpsystems@functorparens}[1]{
    \perfectunary{IncreaseHeight}{(}{)}{#1}
}
```

Secondly, it appears that the perfectcut macros (or, at least, `perfectunary`) don't play nicely with linebreaks inside itself.  In a couple of places in the documentation inside the .dtx file for the package, I had linebreaks inside `cpfunc` macros.  The use of `perfectunary` seems to break these and cause the errors I was seeing.  I tried changing them from `\\` to `\linebreak` based on what I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49622) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91559), which helped, but not totally.  The errors stopped complaining about misplaced `\cr`s but swapped to complaining about misplaced `&`s.  Removing the `&`s got rid of the errors, but now there doesn't seem to be any sort of line breaking at all going on inside either `cpfunc` or `cprule` macros.  Currently, that is a lower priority for me than auto-growing brackets, so it is a trade-off I have made for now.  Hopefully, I will stumble across a way to get that back.

You can find the results of all this at [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jcoo092/LaTeX-cP-systems/releases/tag/v0.15) under release v0.15 if you are interested.